# How do universities verify your native language?

Tags: graduate-admissions, language, language-exams

Many universities require that your native language be English or you will have to submit proof of language proficiency.

Usually if you lie and say English is your native language while all other evidence shows otherwise (e.g. country of birth, country of citizenship, university degree language, etc.), universities will likely suspect that you are lying.

However, suppose my native language is not English but I can read, write, listen, speak as fluently as a native speaker.  If I satisfy one or more conditions below, do universities have any reason to suspect that English is not my native language?

1. I am a citizen of a country where English is the official language (though I may not be born / living there)
2. I graduated from a university where English is the official language

Comment: If I remember correctly in the US satisfying criterion 2 alone is likely sufficient to waive all language requirement.

Comment: @Drecate: Not always—see my answer below.

Comment: You are not native, *but*... Unfortunately whatever comes after the *but* is pretty irrelevant for proving the language skills. You are not native, thus you need to prove your English as any non native. Often after having  had an education in English (e.g. written a Masters or PhD thesis in English) they will waive the language test, but I have met several people that was required to get the IELTS after having written several sceintific papers and a PhD thesis.

Comment: If your language skills are really good enough, you shouldn't have trouble with the language test.

Comment: My university specified that if you didn't meet 1 or 2 you needed to submit results of the TOEFL. Meeting 1 or 2 was considered to be proficient in English.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Actually, there are no universal requirements for waiving testing. For instance, at [MIT](http://gradadmissions.mit.edu/applications/international-applicants/), you establish eligibility for a language waiver by attending *primary and secondary schools* that have English as the language of instruction or by attending an *American* university for your undergraduate education. At [Yale](https://gsas.yale.edu/admissions/required-examinations), you must have attended an English-language university for at least three years to establish eligibility. [Ohio State](https://gpadmissions.osu.edu/intl/english-proficiency.html) only grants exemptions for students graduating from universities in Australia, Belize, the British Caribbean and British West Indies, Canada (except Québec), England, Guyana, Ireland, Liberia, New Zealand, Scotland, the United States and Wales.

So this unfortunately becomes an example of "every school is different, and you need to check the rules for each school."

Comment: Completely unrelated: it’s curious (to me) that, rather than simply including “United Kingdom” in its list, Ohio State lists out the constituent countries (but omits “Northern Ireland”, presumably deeming it to be included within “Ireland”—which could cause upset in some parts).

Comment: @eggyal: Or possibly they've heard people talking with a Northern Irish accent, and couldn't understand what they were saying ;-)

Comment: @psmears Anecdotal evidence from my experience shows there are "significant" amounts of Americans that can't properly understand even a scottish or northern accent.

Comment: @DRF I'd wager a significant proportion of *British* people, let alone Americans, can't understand Glasgow, Geordie or Scouse either. And I found Yorkshire completely opaque when I first moved there as an undergraduate, despite being a native English speaker (albeit not a British one). Accents are *hard*.

Comment: A South African friend of mine from grad school went to an English-language university; our university apparently had a list of countries, like Ohio State does, which did not include South Africa.  (And it probably shouldn't - there are some universities where the language of instruction is Afrikaans.)  He says that he walked in, told the person overseeing that he was there to take the test, and that he was immediately told he didn't have to.

Comment: @eggyal I suspect that's because those constituent countries have their own university regimes.  And would it cause upset, really? Would anyone actually feel excluded by "England, Scotland, Wales, and Ireland"?  I'm aware that the majority in NI wish to belong to the United Kingdom, but that doesn't mean they don't live on the island of Ireland…

Comment: @gerrit: Except that, in a list of countries, “Ireland” is probably taken to mean the republic thereof rather than the island.

Comment: This answer is correct; the criteria vary from school to school. 20 years ago, when I was in charge of graduate admissions, graduating from a U.S. university (with at least 3 years' attendance) was enough to avoid language testing. In at least one case, a student fulfilled that requirement but had lived, throughout his undergraduate studies, with housemates who all spoke his native, far-from-English language. His English was awful, despite his U.S. undergrad degree. I hope (but don't actually know) that the rules may have gotten smarter by now.

Comment: @eggyal: Perhaps because there's a part of the Irish Republic - the Gaeltacht - in which Irish Gaelic is the native tongue.  The same might be true of Scotland & Wales: there are certainly native language movements in both, road signs are in both languages, &c.

Comment: @jamesqf: Surely that would be an argument for *excluding* the Gaeltacht, Scotland and Wales (countries that were all *included*)—albeit I would disagree on the grounds that the universities in those countries all teach in English, and it is graduation from those institutions which is relevant not citizenship/residence of the countries concerned; whilst it also makes no argument in respect of Northern Ireland (which was *omitted*)?

Comment: @eggyal The document linked from the answer says 'who are citizens of, or who have received a bachelor’s degree or higher from'.  But perhaps more troubling than Ohio's segmentation of the UK is wondering what is its motive for omitting the enormous tranche of English-speaking African countries.

Comment: It may be relevant _when_ Ohio's policy was drafted.  Between the British Nationality Act 1948 and the British Nationality Act 1981, "citizen of the United Kingdom" included people from a lot of places other than England, Scotland, Wales, and Northern Ireland.

Answer (score -1):

I knew someone who studied at an Irish university where the language of instruction was Gaelic. There must be at least a few Irish people who do not speak English at all.

Designation by country is silly. Some European universities use English, sometimes mostly and sometimes as one of three acceptable languages.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, there are only about 80000 people with Irish as first language, and there seems to be no indication that there are any adult Irish speakers who are not fluent in English at all.